# RESTful resources and link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

having a bit of trouble. I have a nested routing system:

```
  resources :forums do
    resources :posts
  end
```

Posts belong to forums, I already made the associations in the models.

However, when I visit `/forums/ID/posts`   <===This does not properly render out the index action of the Posts controller. The problem is I don't know how to use link_to when in a nested resource.

```
 @post.each do |post| 
        <li>link_to post.title, post</li>
 end
```

[Took out the ERB syntax]
Here's the Posts controller `index action => @post = Forum.find(params[:id]).posts`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
link_to post.title, forum_post_path(forum,post)
```

Comment: How do I prepare the @forum instance variable in my controller? How about @post? Thank you!

Comment: I presume you want to show all posts of specific forum, right?

Answer (score 0):

Forum id parameter is not right.

```
@post = Forum.find(params[:id]).posts
```

In your PostController you should do

```
 @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
 @posts = @forum.posts
```

And in your view

```
 @posts.each do |post| 
        <li>link_to post.title, post</li>
 end
```

Comment: 'undefined method `post_path' for #<#<Class:0x414b130>:0x3b6c190>' is what appears when I try. Thank you for the help! I feel like I am just making a small mistake.